# Python split, exclude a portion of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

This is the string I am given  `Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas: The,Dave,Make`

I want the list to only include this: `["The", "Dave", "Make"]`

I have tried using split, but it result in an result an error

```
strings = input("Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas:")
strings = strings.split()
```

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried, and clarify where you are stuck.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`string.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) with [`strip()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) methods:

```
In [2680]: s = "Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas: The,Dave,Make"
In [2686]: s.split(':')[-1].strip().split(',')
Out[2686]: ['The', 'Dave', 'Make']
```

Comment: Got it thank you for the help!

Comment: sorry I miss clicked and accepted someone else's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string = 'Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas: The,Dave,Make'

lst = string.split(':')[-1].strip().split(',')
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
['The', 'Dave', 'Make']
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string at the colon, remove extra whitespace, then split at commas.

```py
string = 'Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas: The,Dave,Make'
result = string.split(':')[1].strip().split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string is obtained from the console, its first part should be the input prompt:

```
strings = input("Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas:")
strings = strings.strip().split(',')
```

The code can be shortened into a one-liner:

```
strings = input("Enter 3 random strings, separated by commas:").strip().split(',')
```